# How Does the ECMA Connector Host Configuration Reference DataType Work?

Tags: identity-management

Have been using [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/app-provisioning/on-premises-sql-connector-configure) to set up automatic provisioning between an azure organisation and a SQL based application.

The tutorial seems to be the only source of information explaining how the ECMA Connector Host functions. And it does not go into great detail.

Here, it shows the reference data type.
[image: Schema 4, attribute selection, DataType Reference]

I set the UserID's DataType to reference in Schema 4 and the software adds a new Step, Schema 5, to the list. In there I'm able to set the "Reference UserID" which gives me a list of Object Types I've given the system. And a "Object type column for UserID" which is just a text box.

[image: Schema Detection Step-5: Detect partition for reference attributes. Parition Selection for User. Reference UserID, Object Type column for UserID]

What is the purpose of the Reference data type? When would I use it in my SQL application?

Comment: Side note, very confused as to why this is the only information I can find online. It seems like this software was released some time in 2023. But besides that one link it's like it straight up does not exist.

Comment: Does it ask for more info on the next pages when set to Reference? It may let you add/use a data type definition like for GUIDs. If not, I would assume it refers to the  existing Type from the DB schema

Comment: Do you mean something like the [REF Data Type](https://www.sqliz.com/oracle-ref/ref-type-datatype/)?

Comment: It does ask for more info, yes. I shall add some more clarification as to what it shows.

Comment: @harrymc they might be similar, but I'm using T-SQL and I don't think the Ref DataType exists in there.

Comment: One thing I've noticed is the exceedingly heavy similarities between this and the Generic SQL Connector. I will look to see if I find more information around there.